# Worklight HTTP Adapter not working with Kerberos

Tags: security, ibm-mobilefirst, kerberos, spnego

My team and I are currently doing a Worklight mobile project. One of our requirements is to retrieve data from MS CRM and Sharepoint via web service calls. The authentication mechanism that we are to make use of is Kerberos / Spnego.

We followed the instructions documented [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_the__authentication__element_o.html), where we inserted the following into our HTTP adapter:

```
<authentication>
  <spnego stripPortOffServiceName="true"/>
</authentication>
```

In addition,  as mentioned in the same IBM site we have included the `krb5.conf` file into the `../server/conf` directory in the project files.

However after invoking the adapter procedure, we encountered an error:

> Runtime: Failed to create Kerberos login context

As there are very limited documentation around regarding Worklight working with Kerberos, we were unable to solve this issue. Hence we would like to seek for some help on this community. Is there something that we missed out on?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this type of configuration is not tested often at all and there are no more documentation on this subject matter. This will be discussed to see if documentation and testing can be improved.

The workaround that is currently used (by Desmond) is to continue using NTLM instead.